# Convert videos in background php ffmpeg?

Tags: php, apache, debian, exec

I would like to convert videos with exec(), FFMPEG php. I would like to run the script in background. How can I do that?

```
/*** convert video to flash ***/ 

$v = date('H-i-s');

//   exec("ffmpeg -i uploaded_files/770530705510e88ec723a3-20130111_1221_43.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 flash/".microtime()."video.flv 1> flash/".$v."_block.txt 2>&1");

$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i uploaded_files/770530705510e88ec723a3-20130111_1221_43.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 flash/'.microtime().'.flv';

$outputfile = $v.'.txt.';
$pidfile = $v.'_id.txt.';

      exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

This is my code, but don't do anything. 
I would like to run the script with the php, but I don't want to wait the http loading time until the script is finished...

OR how can I run something.php with exec(); ? If I could run php that was easy me to make all what I needed. (linux debian, apache2, php5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to add a job to a queue and let the server handle the ffmpeg conversion in asynchronous way.

The users has to manually recheck if the server has already finished the job.

You have to do something like this:

1. Create a queue database table.
2. If a new ffmpeg conversion should be done add a job to the queue table.
3. On the server add a cronjob which automatically looks for new jobs and executes your ffmpeg conversion. [More details here.](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)
4. When the cronjob has finished the conversion then mark the job as done, delete it, or whatever.

Comment: And what if I would like to send an e-mail to my user where this is finished? ... Can't I get an automatic report.. Like.. after finished automaticali insert an sql record... ?

Comment: Could you tell me how? A simple example, please? It would be really helpfull for me..

Comment: You mean crontab. I see, but is that possibe without cronjob? Crontab?  Now my FFMPEG is working well. I get back informaitons about my convertion too, but I would like to run X.php after it finished...

Comment: You have to put the conversion in a PHP file and run the PHP file with crontab. Then you can run other PHP code after the conversion.

Comment: You don't understood me... There is a file, like converter.php ... In file i do exec(FFMPEG...);
after that sql_qery... 
I have an another file, index.php with exec(converter.php)... What is the right sintax, if I would like to run converter.php in background and FFMPEG in non background. This is my logic. It should be work, I think...